# How can I represent a vector equation of a line segment in C++?

Tags: c++, vector, graphics, line

I am working with computer graphics.

I would like to represent a line with two end points, and, then I would like my `Line2d` class to have a method that returns a `Vector2d` object.

Suppose, I have the following classes:

```
struct Point2d
{
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

Then, I can easily represent a line segment using two points:

```
class LineSegment2d
{
private:
    Point2d start;
    Point2d end;
public:
    ...
    ...
};
```

According to the definition, a vector is composed of a magnitude and a direction.

```
class Vector2d
{
private:
    Point2d p;
public:
    double Magnitude(void);
    Point Component(void);
    Vector2d Normal();
    Vector2d & Add(Vector & rhs);
    Vector2d & Subtract(Vector & rhs);
    Vector2d & Multiply(int scalar);
    int DotProduct(Vector2d rhs);
    Vector2d & CrossProduct(Vector2d rhs);
};
```

One object of `Point2d` is sufficient to represent a vector. For example, magnitude of a vector = `sqrt(p.x*p.x + p.y*p.y);`. And, `p.x` and `p.y` collectively represent the direction.

---

On the other hand, we know that the vector equation of a line passing through `(x0,y0,z0)` is, `r =r0 + tv`
Where, 
`r` is the vector for the subject line.
`r0`  is a position vector that points to the direction of the point `(x0, y0, z0)`. Since, r0  is a position vector, obviously, the origin of r0  would be `(0,0,0)`.
`t` is any real numbered value, where, `−∞<t<∞ –`.
`v` is a vector which is parallel to our subject straight line.

Vector equation of a line segment between the points `P(1, 3, 2)` and `Q(-4, 3, 0)`:

According to the above formula, the vector equation of the line `PQ` could be either

```
r =<1,3,2> + tv
```

or,

```
r =<-4,3,0> + tv
```

The vector that connects the two points `P` and `Q` is,

```
PQ  = <(-4-1), (3-3), (0-2)>
    = <-5, 0, -2>
```

And, this vector is parallel to our subject line for sure.

So, we can write,

```
r   =<1, 3, 2> + t <-5, 0, -2>
    =<1, 3, 2>+<-5t, 0, -2t>
    = <(1-5t), (3+0), (2-2t)>
    =<1-5t, 3, 2-2t>
```

According to the vector equation of a line segment, I think, my Vector class should look like the following:

```
class LineVector2d
{
private:
    Vector2d v;
    double t;
public:
    ..........
};
```

**Is this the correct representation?**

If that so, how can I calculate/set/find the value of `t`?

Comment: What is it really that you ask? You lost me with all the questions within the question.

Comment: Which vector should the method return on the Line2d class?

Comment: The magnitude of a vector with `int` coordinates is not always an `int` (e.g. (1,1) had magnitude sqrt(2).

Comment: As I understand it inbound or outbound is not a property of an edge, but a property of a specific intersection between an edge and a polygon (a long edge can have an inbound *and* outbound intersection with a polygon.  Hence this is not an edge property.

Comment: http://www.ck12.org/search/?q=domain:Directed%20Line%20Segments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's some confusion because of the following

> According to the definition, a vector is composed of a magnitude and a direction.

There is more than one way of representing a vector. I think in your question you mean that a vector can be represented by a magnitude (scalar) and a unit vector indicating a direction. A vector can just be an ordered triplet (for three dimensions) that indicate the magnitude (`sqrt(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)`) and the direction from the origin.

I think the answer to your question is, you don't need to calculate `t`. Correct me if I'm mistaken, but I think you're interpreting `t` as the magnitude? You can calculate that from `v` with `sqrt(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)`, but `v` can hold both a magnitude and direction as an ordered triplet by itself.

**Edit:**

```
template <typename T>
struct Point2d
{
    T x;
    T y;

    Point2d operator + (const Point2d<T>& rhs) const
    {
        return Point2d<T>{x + rhs.x, y + rhs.y};
    }
    Point2d operator - (const Point2d<T>& rhs) const
    {
        return Point2d<T>{x - rhs.x, y - rhs.y};
    }
    // ...

    Point2d operator * (const T value) const
    {
        return Point2d<T>{x*value, y*value};
    }
    Point2d operator / (const T value) const
    {
        return Point2d<T>{x/value, y/value};
    }
    // ...
};

template <typename T>
class Vector2d
{
private:
    Point2d<T> p;
public:
    Vector2d(const Point2d<T>& point) : p{point} {}

    /*double Magnitude();
    Point2d<T> Component();
    Vector2d Normal();
    int DotProduct(Vector2d rhs);
    Vector2d& CrossProduct(Vector2d rhs);*/

    Vector2d operator + (const Vector2d<T>& rhs) const
    {
        return p + rhs.p;
    }
    Vector2d operator - (const Vector2d<T>& rhs) const
    {
        return p - rhs.p;
    }
    // ...

    Vector2d operator * (const T value) const
    {
        return p*value;
    }
    Vector2d operator / (const T value) const
    {
        return p/value;
    }
    // ...
};

template <typename T>
class LineVector2d
{
private:
    Point2d<T>  p;
    Vector2d<T> v;

public:
    LineVector2d() = default;
    LineVector2d(const Point2d<T>& point, const Vector2d<T>& direction) : p{point}, v{direction} {}

    /// Returns the point on the line for the time/value `t`
    Point2d<T> valueAt(T t)
    {
        return p + v*t;
    }
};
```

Comment: @BROY Could you clarify what `LineVector2d` is supposed to do beyond what `Vector2d` does? I think that would help answer "how can I calculate/set/find the value of `t`?"

Comment: Ok. But, how do you feed the value of t? Where do you find/calculate/determine the value of t in Point2d<T> valueAt(T t)?

Comment: @BROY That's what I'm confused about, `t` varies from -infinity to +infinity, you can input anything to get points on the line starting with `p/point` at `t = 0`. As a shot in the dark: are you trying to calculate an intersection with something and want the `t` value where that happens?

Answer (score 4):

There are [many forms of line representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation#Forms_for_two-dimensional_linear_equations).

If you mean line (not segment), then, probably, you'll find convenient to use class/structure, containing BasePoint and UnitDirectionVector.

For line segments, choose between (`Point pt0, Point pt1`) form, and, (`Point pt, Vector v = pt1 - pt0`) form.

The second one is more suitable for parametric approach like, 
`X = P0.X + t * D.X` etc.

Comment: Line segment is limited, so vector D has definite length (length of segment). For line there is no sense to store direction vector length, so unit direction vector is better (for some calculations)

Comment: I have not c# code, but think that any geometric library written in c# contains needed primitives

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert a line segment to a vector, you have to be aware that there is no "universal semantic" for the conversion, it is up to you to define what the conversion means. That said, I assume you want a vector with the same (Euclidean) norm as the length of the line segment and pointing in the same direction, i.e. something like this:

```
class LineSegment2d
{
   ....
   Vector2d getVector() const {
      return Vector2d(end) - Vector2d(start);
   }
};
```

In other words, offset the line segment to the origin point of the coordinate system. The end point can then be converted to a vector.

EDIT: After understanding a bit more about why you want this, you might be looking for another representation

```
class LineSegment2d
{
   ....
   Vector2d getVector() const {
      return Vector2d(end);
   }
};
```

This will get you one vector for each line segment: the end point. If your polygons consist of connected line segments, this will give you all the vertices in the polygon.

Comment: I am actually working with the Weiler-Atherton algorithm. This algorithm requires to distinguish polygon edges between inbound and outbound ones. I am not sure, how my representation of `Line2d` with `start` and `end` can serve this purpose. That is why I am wondering whether I am in need of a vector representation.

Comment: Hmm. Are you sure you don't want the *vertices* of each polygon segment instead? (Disclaimer: after a minute or two skimming through the Wikipedia page)

Comment: I think the algorithm could be implemented by using the end points and following the line segments clockwise in order.

Answer (score 1):

Use the representation of line segments you have in the question.

I'll write `LS(a,b)` for the line segment with start point `a`, and, end point `b`.

Now given two such segments `LS(a,b)`, and, `LS(c,d)` that intersect (in your context one from the clipping polygon and one from the polygon being clipped; I am presuming you know how to determine this).

What you seem to want answered is if this intersection has `LS(c,d)` going to the inside of the polygon while crossing the edge `LS(a,b)`.

For this, it is sufficient to determine the angle between the directions of the line segments. This is the same as the angle between the vectors `v = b-a` and `w = d-c`.

Also, you don't even need the angle, all you need is to see if the angle is positive or negative; so look at the vector `w-v`. If `LS(c,d)` crosses `LS(a,b)` to the inside, this vector will be in the lower half plane. If `LS(c,d)` crosses `LS(a,b)` to the outside, this vector will be in the upper half plane.

Determining upper verses lower half plane means looking at the second coordinate of `end-start`.

Apologies for the wall of text, but mathjax doesn't seem active on this site.  Also no code, but I believe that (if I didn't make any mistakes) all the operations I mentioned are easy to translate into code.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=angle+between+vector+%7B0%2C180%7D+%7B180%2C0%7D

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=angle+between+vector+%7B0%2C180%7D+%7B-180%2C0%7D

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be very mathematical, maybe this can help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates

In 2d that means a position is (x,y,1) and a direction (dx,dy,0). The reason for this is projection, which is rare in 2d but common in 3d.

So to try to answer: Just use 4 component vectors all the time. Positions have a w=1, directions a w=0.

Just try it with a line based of two points A and B, both have w=1. The vector from A to B is B-A, which ends up with w=0.

Also what you use in your code does matter very little unless you end up optimizing a special case. Just go for the smallest data structure. Start and end should be fine.

Maybe think about indexed: A flat array of all vertices and every line is just two indices into the vertex array.

Comment: can you write some  C++ code to show what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

Your representation of class `LineSegment2d` is fine. But the representation of class `Vector2d` is incorrect. This is because you are considering only those vectors that pass through the origin. A vector on a 2d plane can be represented with 3 components in the same way it done in 3d space. The 3 components of a vector are namely: Direction, Magnitude and A point through which it passes. If we define x, y and z axes for a 3d space then, for a point in the x-y plane z component is equal to 0. Also, direction in 3d space is defined in the form of direction cosines(ie. the cosine of the angle between the vector and an axis). Hence cosine of angle between vector and z-axis is equal to zero(because the angle = 90 degrees) for a vector in x-y plane.

Comment: Just write a perfect class Line2d along with explanation so that I can represent a line using vectros and I will accept your answer and upvote you and award the bounty of 100 points. That's all.

Comment: You want me to write class Line2d or Vector2d