# Recognizing Vector equation of line segment (Python)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a ray casting program, and I need to recognize segmented lines in Python 3. How else can I represent the vector equation of a line segment in matplotlib?

```
r(t) = (a,b,c) + t<x,y,z>

point1 = (3,4)
point2 = (8,9)
t = 1         # I'm not sure how to define t other than this
v1 = point1 + t * [point2[0] - point1[0], point2[1] - point1[0]]
```

I recognize this is terribly wrong but I'm stuck. There's a similar question to this that's already been answered ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31273441/how-can-i-represent-a-vector-equation-of-a-line-segment-in-c)) but I'm still very new to programming overall and was hoping for a simpler explanation.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to create an equation of a segmented line (so a line that is only defined for a specific range of points). In my case I actually need to turn the sides of a rectangle/triangle into vectors in order to find the intersection with a ray that I cast out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you show translated into python using numpy would look like this

```
import numpy as np

point1 = np.array((3,4))
point2 = np.array((8,9))

f = lambda t: point1 + t * (point2-point1)

print( f(0) )    # [3 4]
print( f(0.5) )  # [ 5.5  6.5]
print( f(1) )    # [8 9]
```